# I don't want to release open stored procedure to my customer. C# , .NET, SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a software with C# running on .NET that uses SQL Server stored procedures.

I don't want to release open stored procedures to my customer. I used the `WITH ENCRYPTION` clause but it is easily bypassed.

I'm thinking of insert my stored procedures in a dll to compile and use in C# but with CLR stored procedure, I have to rewrite them and I wouldn't want to do it because they work fine.

Are there any suggestions?

How do you protect your stored procedures?

Thank you.

Comment: If the SQL Server database runs at the customer's site, under their control, you cannot prevent the customer from accessing the procedure's code.

Comment: snarky counter question. How should a customer protect itself from your stored proc? Or to phrase it differently if you don't trust them why should they trust you? Is it really necessary that your customer can't see what you are doing?

Comment: @ralf For security reasons I don't want them to get their hands on the code

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn But is it possible that the stored procedure  cannot be encapsulated in a dll?

Comment: Never really understood the need for this unless you have some super-secret proprietary algorithms... virtually anything can be reversed engineered.    I suspect your clients care more about the information than the code behind it.  If you truly need to protect your code, then host the database and provide a restrictive front end.

Comment: Perhaps it contains a password or similar "secret" information?

Comment: This is the reason why SaaS platforms exist. The problem that you have is that the infrastructure lives in the "customer's" environment. It is unlikely that you're going to be able to hide source code from them when it's in their environment. It's even less likely that they're going to let you deploy unreadable code in their environment.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes, I have a super secret algorithm ... I'm playing :-). I don't want the customer to modify the code themselves in production. I will give them a CD with all the sources but I don't wish they could do it in production. That's all. And I can't bring the management to my database.

Comment: @loky This is more of a business practice issue than it is a technical one. Set the expectation with the customer that they are not covered under the existing support model if they edit the source code. Advise them to have their DBAdmin secure the stored procedure behind a certain level of access to prevent any unneeded costs.

Comment: Then use a contract.  There's no technical means to do what you propose,  which is by design.  It's not your SQL Server, not your data.

Comment: You can write code that can extract all the Stored Procedures, hash them and then compare the hashes.  If they make a change and then phone you at 4:00am, run that tool first

Comment: @Flydog57 This is a good idea !!

Comment: @ChrisPhillips Thanks Chris, the contractual aspect is important but I was looking for a way to do it technically. I thought it was simple and tried asking for help here but it seems not possible without rewriting the stored procedures.
Apparently no one asks this question or considers it an ethical and not a technical problem. It's probably a false problem of mine. I don't have to use the Stored Procedures but write all the code in c #

Comment: _but write all the code in c #_ which can be decompiled. You cannot protect code or data that someone can directly access. And why would anyone trust you if you hide your code from inspection? Is there a bitcoin miner secretly embedded in it? See how this works both ways?

Comment: @Smor But the problem isn't decompiling the code or mining bitcoin. I repeat it seems to me that you are looking at the ethical problem. The customer still has a copy of the source code. I don't want them to make any changes to the stored procedures in production. I wanted to avoid rewriting my Stored Procedures. If you tell me that it can't be done I create and deliver an exe and I solved it. That's enough.

Comment: Ethics are not a consideration; this is simply the consequence of how modern computer architectures "work". This is essentially the DRM problem: unless you are in control of the hardware itself, you cannot 1) prevent the hardware from running code you don't want it to run, or 2) force it to run code you *do* want it to run. You can add as many layers of obfuscation, encryption and active checks to your code as desired to make it as difficult as possible for the customer, but as long as all code lives on the local machine, it's a technical impossibility to make such measures airtight.

Comment: It is *utterly impossible* to prevent someone from being able to decompile your code, especially in C#. You can only make it difficult and/or slow them down. And given you are using an external database product that you need to communicate with, it's not possible at all. Even if you remove procedures and place the SQL in your C# code, they could run a server-side trace. And if you think you can disable their access to SQL Server, it's pretty trivial to break into if you have admin access to the machine. Creating an `exe` won't help you at all here.